# Pandas: create a dataframe from 2D numpy arrays preserving their sequential order

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Say that you have 3 numpy arrays: `lat`, `lon`, `val`:

```
import numpy as np

lat=np.array([[10, 20, 30],
              [20, 11, 33],
              [21, 20, 10]])

lon=np.array([[100, 102, 103],
              [105, 101, 102],
              [100, 102, 103]])

val=np.array([[17, 2, 11],
              [86, 84, 1],
              [9, 5, 10]])
```

And say that you want to create a `pandas` dataframe where `df.columns = ['lat', 'lon', 'val']`, but since each value in `lat` is associated with both a `long` and a `val` quantity, you want them to appear in the same row.

Also, you want the row-wise order of each column to follow the positions in each array, so to obtain the following dataframe:

```
      lat   lon   val
0     10    100    17
1     20    102    2
2     30    103    11
3     20    105    86
...   ...   ...    ...
```

So basically the first row in the dataframe stores the "first" quantities of each array, and so forth. **How to do this?**

I couldn't find a pythonic way of doing this, so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is flattening the arrays by using [ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat.ravel(), 'long': long.ravel(), 'val': val.ravel()})
print (df)
   lat  long  val
0   10   100   17
1   20   102    2
2   30   103   11
3   20   105   86
4   11   101   84
5   33   102    1
6   21   100    9
7   20   102    5
8   10   103   10
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this -

```
# Create stacked array
In [100]: arr = np.column_stack((lat.ravel(),long.ravel(),val.ravel()))

# Create dataframe from it and assign column names    
In [101]: pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=('lat','long','val'))
Out[101]: 
   lat  long  val
0   10   100   17
1   20   102    2
2   30   103   11
3   20   105   86
4   11   101   84
5   33   102    1
6   21   100    9
7   20   102    5
8   10   103   10
```

Runtime test -

```
In [103]: lat = np.random.rand(30,30)

In [104]: long = np.random.rand(30,30)

In [105]: val = np.random.rand(30,30)

In [106]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat.ravel(), 'long': long.ravel(), 'val': val.ravel()})
1000 loops, best of 3: 452 µs per loop

In [107]: arr = np.column_stack((lat.ravel(),long.ravel(),val.ravel()))

In [108]: %timeit np.column_stack((lat.ravel(),long.ravel(),val.ravel()))
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.4 µs per loop

In [109]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=('lat','long','val'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 217 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to ravel first. You can just stack and go.

```
lat, long, val = np.arange(5), np.arange(5), np.arange(5)
arr = np.stack((lat, long, val), axis=1)
cols = ['lat', 'long', 'val']
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=cols)
   lat  long  val
0    0     0    0
1    1     1    1
2    2     2    2
3    3     3    3
4    4     4    4
```